# How to make google map full width with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

Map doesn't work when I make it full width. 
Here's my HTML code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
         <div id="map"></div>
         <script>
            function initMap() {
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
                  center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
                  zoom: 8
                });
             }
          </script>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS Code :**

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

But it doesn't display the map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not giving height to map. Give him some height.further you can check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/zq1fvgnj/3/

Comment: Give your map container a fixed height, or if you can't, calculate it with JS and set it before your create the map.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the height, like this:

```
#map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height:500px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to call you `initMap()` function on `document.ready` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMap();
})
```

Next add some imaginary height to your `#map`

```
#map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    height: 400px;
}
```

## `Demo Here`

`Javascript` equivalent for `document.ready`

```
(function() {
   initMap();
})();
```

Comment: Did OP mention jQuery?

Comment: @MrUpsidown.. By `jquery`, if you meant by adding tags, then OP never mentioned `javascript` neither but he had `javascript` code there. Basically he just declared the `function` and never called it. That's the key point here. Not `document.ready` or its equivalent solution in `javascript`.